# Security of encrypted Apple .dmg file?

Tags: encryption

are there any information (in deep / cracking) about how secure a .dmg file is when encrypting it with 128 or 256 bit of AES?

I didn't find any documentation about it but I might just be too silly to find it. I would like to know how secure it is and if there is a possibility of a backdoor withing the file.

Answer (score 3):

About DMG and AES in general

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110369/are-the-files-in-an-encrypted-dmg-actually-in-plain-text-on-the-hard-disk/110618
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537418/how-secure-is-aes-128

About DMG "cracking" (infact he just bruteforces it because he knows most of the password and just has to test about 22k password combinations):

- https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/cracking-aes-256-dmgs-and-epic-self-pwnage/

At least there are no known implementation failures of which I am aware (there was some kind of bug around 2006).

With DMG Encryption on Mac OSX AES 128/256 is used which is commonly considered to be a safe encryption method (of course depending on your password).

So if your password is good (long, lower/uppercase letters, special characters, etc.) then it is safe

Comment: Thanks but I'm curious because Apple is in the US. I'm so afraid because Lavabit were in the US as well.